# Node.js convert HEIC file

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I need a way to use Node.js to convert a photo from HEIC format to either jpg or png. I have searched and cannot seem to find anything that works.

Comment: If you can use a browser environment, take a look at https://github.com/alexcorvi/heic2any. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudmersive-image-api-client is a service which provides the same but for a price (free tier available at 1000 calls/5mb limit at the moment tho)

Answer (score -31, accepted):

Changing the filename is sufficient for viewing HEIC as jpg:

`const fileName = photo.fileName.split(".")[0] + ".jpg";`

Comment: Oh god no! Please don't do this. It's not sufficient at all. You might be lucky that your viewer could handle this. But it's not possible to work with such file. Any other program might report this as a corrupted file.

Comment: this has been working great for over a year now!

Comment: @BrandonB It's working because images (and other file types often) have a type encoded in the first few bytes. Your image reader is using that data to determine the file type (not the file extension).

Answer (score 10):

**npm -i heic-convert**

```
const convert = require('heic-convert');
async function heicToPng(file, output) {
    console.log(file, output);
    const inputBuffer = await promisify(fs.readFile)(file);
    const outputBuffer = convert({
        buffer: inputBuffer, // the HEIC file buffer
        format: 'PNG', // output format
    });
    return promisify(fs.writeFile)(output, outputBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Your function name is heicToJpg but format passed to convert fn is png. You may want to change that.

Answer (score 1):

With heic-convert as Bruno suggested, it works fine.
Here is a node utility that allows you to serially convert HEIC files present in a folder: [convert-heic-files](https://github.com/usualpro/convert-heic-files/)