# Google Vision OCR cannot detect text or images when using the .HEIC image type

Tags: node.js, google-vision

I am having an issue uploading iPhone photos. The default iPhone image is a .HEIC file. Google vision seems to have a hard time reading these file types. It works fine when using .jpg files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are coding in nodejs maybe use this library to convert and upload:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/heic-convert

There are online tools as well on the web:
https://heictojpg.com/

Answer (score 0):

Heic is [not supported directly](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files)

You can convert each image and send it to the google API, if you have access to the source iPhone you can change the settings to avoid using Heic as default format.

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018547/node-js-convert-heic-file) relevant question